# How to access column in groupby? - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following pandas DataFrame dt:

```
   auftragskennung    sku       artikel_bezeichnung  summen_netto      system_created
0               14    200182        Product 1         -16.64         2015-05-12 19:55:16
1               14    730293        Product 2         -4.16          2015-05-12 19:55:16
2                3    720933        Product 3          0.00          2014-03-25 12:12:44
3                3    192042        Product 4         19.95          2014-03-25 12:12:45
4                3    423902        Product 5         23.88          2014-03-25 12:12:45
```

I then execute this command to get the best selling products ordered by sku:

```
topseller = dt.groupby("sku").agg({"summen_netto": np.sum}).sort("summen_netto", ascending=False)
```

Which returns something like:

```
           summen_netto
sku              
730293         55622.24
720933         35603.99
192042         27698.99
423902         26726.28
734630         25730.21
740353         22798.14
```

This is what I want, but how can I now access the sku column? `topseller["sku"]` does not work. It always gives me a KeyError.

I would like to be able to do this:

```
topseller["sku"]["730293"]
```

Which would then return 55622.24

Comment: I did now. I am pretty new to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sku is now the column so you need to use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) to perform label selection:

```
In [7]:

topseller.loc[730293]
Out[7]:
summen_netto   -4.16
Name: 730293, dtype: float64
```

You can confirm this here:

```
In [8]:

topseller.index
Out[8]:
Int64Index([423902, 192042, 720933, 730293, 200182], dtype='int64', name='sku')
```